# Integration test for API that has @Secured

Tags: spring, spring-security, integration-testing, keycloak, testcontainers

I have a spring REST API that is secured by spring security and Keycloak, and I am using keycloak testcontainers for the integration test.  I can add a user to keycloak and get a token to use while testing most of the APIs.

The question is, If I have an API that is annotated with @Secured to limit its access to only users with a specific role, how to assign that role to the created user or mock this role to run the integration test

Comment: Do you really need it to be a integration test? If not, you can use `@WebMvcTest` in combination with `@WithMockUser`

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio `@WithMockUser` populates unit-test security context with a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` instance when a `JwtAuthenticationToken` (if using `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`) or `KeycloakAuthenticationToken` (if using the [deprecated Keycloak libs for Spring](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187)) might be needed for security expressions evaluation. See `@WithMockKeycloakAuth` and `@WithMockJwtAuth` annotations from [this repo](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) instead

Answer (score 1):

You may simply want to add the role to the user, e.g. like this:

```java
RoleRepresentation role = new RoleRepresentation("rolename", "role desc", false);
KeycloakContainer container = new KeycloakContainer();        
RealmResource realm = container.getKeycloakAdminClient().realm("realm");
realm.roles().create(role);
realm
  .users()
  .get("user")
  .roles()
  .realmLevel()
  .add(List.of(role));
```